# How to edit private methods in a git repository so that it is maintainable

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-fork

So, I just love a repository(REPO) I found on GitHub , however, the creator of that that repo is too sensitive to what he exposes as `public(open)`. So, other than the primary necessities he makes every thing else(classes, functions, variables... ) `private`.

However, I need to access and modify the forbidden fruit, the `private variables, classes, methods, ...` which are located in just 1 file in the repo. So, my question is how can I make changes to that file, so that my work is as maintainable as possible.

Maintainable meaning: when the REPO owner updates the repo, it should be as *easy* as possible for me to update the REPO in my and my teams setup

Well, specifically, I just need to change 1 class file in a `Swift` GitHub library which I have installed using `cocoapods`

Comment: You probably get some better answer if you add language to the tags. Some languages allows accessing private members without modifying source.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question actually. It is a pain of many projects that depend on open source libraries. At some point your use case appears to be a bit different from the original authors use cases, and you have to modify the code. As soon as you do that, you get a certain maintenance burden, because you have to keep track of your patches and refactor/reapply them when the upstream repo (your dependency) updates. For example [FreeBSD Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports) and [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) are projects that try to cope with this problem at scale. In simple words they maintain a collection of patches which adapt Linux software (from original repos) to BSD/Mac (their own "forks").

There's no magic bullet here, but I'd say that git simplifies the process greatly in many cases. For example, you can make a branch in your fork that contains your changes, and then when time comes to update, you do "git rebase" onto the new master branch (resolving the conflicts etc.).

For your particular case I'd recommend to make a script that prepares a patch automatically: search through your file and change all "private" to "public". This script can be as simple as `sed -i s/private/public/g TheirShyFile.swift`. If you have such a script, it will be much easier to maintain your fork, because instead of rebasing and resolving conflicts, you just fork again from master and apply your script again.

Comment: yeah, but as you meant, it is not the perfect solution. I now have to maintain 2 repos. First my original project, second the forked repo. 

Can I do it in the original main project?

Comment: Yes, in some sense the perfect would be to convince the maintainer that your changes are good to take them upstream. But that might be actually much more work. Usually they have some other idea in mind to improve an architecture so that it fits your use case, and it will require a much broader change, negotiations, tests etc. To me that's not perfect from the business point of view. It's finally up to you to decide.

Comment: @rahulg, though I may argue your git tags are not eligible for your problem, I agree with battlmonstr that you need to supply a patcher on your own fork to patch updated codes of the original repo, then make merge/rebase or whatever needed to distribute it to your team. Also, dont forget to select an answer if you find one of them useful (not mine).

Answer (score 1):

Fork the repo. Then checkout your fork of the repo locally and modify code as you see fit. Commit your changes and push to your repo.

Finally, submit a pull request to the original repo, which will need to be approved by the code author/maintainer.